# Communicate with moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

How can I communicate with moderators ?

Sometimes I really need to communicate with eligible and responsible member (moderators are meant to be in this criteria) to figure out why isn't my profile growing and why I am not getting proper responses.

Sometimes when I try to post question it doesn't allow me to post because of some reason (I believe its not grammar) and as result I have to drop the idea to post question. I read the standards but and try to follow them but I think i am missing something that can be traced with help of moderators.

I also need to understand the concepts by communicating with other members and want to be a part of discussions if there are some.

Comment: Everything you mentioned in your question can (and mostly should) be asked as questions on Meta (as you just did but as separate questions) rather than bother a moderator. You then get a larger audience of knowledgeable users, *and* possibly moderators answering. As for your last part (in fact all of what you asked really) you would likely find info already present through searches :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every site has a chat room (accessible from the `Stack Exchange` button at the top left, and clicking `chat` next to the current site name) where you can talk to anybody as long as you have 20 rep.

Some sites even have a specific 'mod chat room' if you want your message to (mainly) be seen by mods.

The only problem with chat is that nothing is private - whatever you post can be seen with everyone, but on most occasions that would be fine.

If you don't understand why an error message is shown, or what it means, search on Meta, and then if you can't find an answer, post it on the child-meta of the site you experience the error on - mods (and normal users) from that site will be able to help you!